# Is there an acceptable ratio of pause frames?

Tags: ethernet, cisco-nexus-2000, fcoe

At the risk of asking an opinion question, are there any guidelines/practices that specify a threshold where the number of pause frames indicates a problem?

The ratio of transmitted pause frames to received frames is about 3%.  If I assume xon/xoff, that's really about 1.5% of received packets are generating pauses.

I'm trying to figure out if I have a serious over-subscription problem.

Hardware is Nexus 2232pp, linked to a 5000.  Flow control is the default settings (transmit on).

Comment: That's a FEX, so  it's pretty easy to oversubscribe the hell out of it. If you aren't seeing issues with dropped packets (or jitter), then I'd say ignore it. (I don't even look at the pause frame counts until something is b0rked.)

Comment: Are you seeing pauses in or outbound on the host interfaces of the N2k?  Or is this on the fabric interface to the N5k?  Also how many interfaces do you have active as downlink/uplinks to the N2k?

Comment: Outbound on the host interface (connected to a NAS).  They have two uplinks